# What is phase coherence?

Tags: magnetic-fields

What is [phase coherence](http://www.google.com/search?as_q=phase+coherence+mri)? I have exam next week in MRI, and I can't understand this sentence:

> Time T2 relates to loss of resonance and thus the loss of transversal magnetization. This occurs due to slightly energy transitions between neighboring nuclei, inducing slightly different rates of rotation and loss of resonance (phase coherence).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In pulsed NMR we start with the dipoles all aligned with the magnetic field (call this the $z$ axis) then we apply a pulse to rotate all the dipoles onto the $x$ axis i.e. at 90º to the $z$ axis. The spins now start rotating in the $xy$ plane and we measure the frequency of rotation to get the dipole moment.

the trouble is that the dipoles are all of slightly different strengths and so they all rotate at slightly different speeds. This means that although they start out all pointing in the same direction (along the $x$ axis) they end up orientated randomly in the $xy$ plane so the net dipole is zero and we can no longer measure it.

So immediately after the pulse we measure a strong signal, but as the dipoles spread out in the $xy$ plane they start cancelling each other out and the strength of the signal we measure falls in a roughly exponential fashion. The time constant for this exponential fall is called $T_2$.

Note that this is different from (usually shorter than) the time constant $T_1$ for the dipoles to decay back to be aligned on the $z$ axis.